# Spring Security with external authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a working spring security that works againts a local db. Now I'd like to move the authentication part by calling a webservice as follow

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        boolean valid = rt.getForObject(HostConfig.HOST+"/authenticate?username=hq&password=a123456",Boolean.class);
```

The above service returns true or false.

I'd like to know on which class I should override the existing authentication with the above. Any ideas?

Comment: i think a better approach is to configure it in your XML - Spring has examples of how to configure data-source...

Comment: I need to authenticate based on the returned boolean flag. What data source are you referring too ?

Comment: i see. i've asnwered - hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` is the thing that you are looking for. You should implement the method   `loadUserByUsername()`, and check the password etc.

HTH

Comment: I only have the access to the username. The password check should happen on the external rest call. I guess I need to know how to instantiate authentication and set it to the security context?